# Bundle não rendeniza css asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho meu bundle

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

E simplesmente parou de funcionar, ele não rendeniza nada

O bundle está sendo registrado no global.asax

```
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

E ao desabilitar o EnableOptimizations

```
  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Ele rendeniza o css, mas sem mesclar

Comment: O que é gerado no HTML? Por acaso você não tem uma pasta com esse nome?

Comment: não gera nada, e tenho a pasta com nome de Content sim, até esse @Style render é o padrão que vem ao criar o projeto

Comment: no seu arquivo `BlundeConfig.cs` dentro da pasta `App_Start` ta assim `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));`

Comment: Sim Maria, dessa forma, vem padrão ao gerar um projeto asp.net mvc 5 no visual studio, não fiz absolutamente nada, estava funcionando, simplesmente parou e não funcionou mais, não sei se atualizaram algo

Comment: Pode verificar se no Global.asax o seu bundle está sendo registrado corretament, por favor?

Comment: vi algumas coisas, e editei a pergunta

Comment: Você por um acaso criou um diretório chamado `css` dentro de `Content`?

Comment: Sim, agora vi, uma lib que peguei pelo nuget criou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diretórios criados pelo Visual Studio são gerenciados pelo IIS, o que proíbe o *Bundling* de criar os arquivos temporários.

Simplesmente apague o diretório `/Content/css` que o *Bundling* voltará a funcionar.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, deve-se apagar a pasta e criar outra com outro nome para salvar os aquivos de estilo? Já tive um problema semelhante, mas com os scripts, será que poderia ser a mesma coisa (mas o erro ocorreu não no local, mas ao publicar no servidor de produção)?

Comment: Não. Apenas apagar o diretório. Quando o diretório não existe, o IIS é responsável por criá-lo e gerenciá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Também já tive esse problema, e a solução passou ir às configurações do projeto e marquei a opção: "Override application root URL"